# font sizes in responsive html5 css website

Tags: android, ios, css, html

I am re-designing my website to work on all browsers and devices and to do so I started from a responsive template that I purchased.
I am new to responsive design. 
My question is about font sizes.
I am trying to have a H-U-G-E headline title (full screen) that will look big on all devices.
I am not an expert at CSS, but I read that 'em' is used for relative/proportional sizes of fonts so I had set the font of the headline to 4em, which is about as big as 500px appear on the screen of the computer but when I look at the page on my iPhone the headline is tiny, smaller than other texts.

Should I just stick to sizes in 'px' and find what works for screen and iOS screen or is there a way to do this that will work on all devices?

The template I am using does have this line at the top:

> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
> ```

Comment: If you want a headline to be the same size relative to the screen width, you should look into the `vw` unit rather than `px`. `1vw` is one percent of the screen width. Anyway, `4em` can't possibly be smaller than the surrounding texts; that is not how ems work. `4em` is four times as large as the surrounding text. If that doesn't work the same on all devices, you're doing it wrong. Maybe a media query is messing things up?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion... i just tried 'vw' and the same thing happens: on computer it's huge and then on iOS it's tiny... how can I trouble shoot this and understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do responsive-text in your website, you should try the [Media Queries.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
This a simple way to size your text on the different screen size.

for example if you want a 500px h1 on your screen that are larger than 1200px, you'll write :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
h1.
{ 
font-size: 500px;
}
```

And so on, on each screen [size](https://static.joomlart.com/images/userguide/support-faqs/responsive-media-queries.png)

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
h1.
{ 
font-size: 300px;
}
```

I hope I've helped you, let me know..

Comment: thank you, that's helpful, I'll try that... how many sizes should I account for? is there no way to do it proportional so I don't have to enter too many screen sizes?

Comment: Well  the different screen sizess are :
>= 1200 px for large screen (from large pc screen to tv)
between 992 and 1199 px for normal desktop screen,
between 768 and 991px for tablet screen,
and between 480 and 767 px for mobile screen.

In fact test yourself by open console in chrome with "f12", then when your console is open, shrink the page, you'll see at the right top the screen size in pixels.
And yes you are kind of forced to specifie every size for every screen sizes, it's not that hard when you become use to, and it's very helpfull.